# MIPS - Delete consecutive duplicates from input

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to convert a program written in java to mips.

The program asks user to enter a string and delete consecutive duplicates. For example if the users enters "abbcddeffga", the output would be "abcdefga".

In Java everything works fine, but in MIPS I've probably messed up something with the registers or something else, and now I don't how to fix it (I'm a newbie in MIPS).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("String? ");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    int length = s.length();
    String res = "";

    if(length == 1)
        System.out.println(s);

    else {
    for(int i = 1; i < length; i++)
        for(int j = i; j < length; j++) {
            if(s.charAt(i - 1) != s.charAt(j)) {
                if(i == length - 1) {
                    if(length == 2 || s.charAt(i - 1) != s.charAt(i - 2)) {
                        res+= s.charAt(i - 1);
                        res+= s.charAt(j);
                    }
                    else
                        res+= s.charAt(j);
                }
                else {
                    res += s.charAt(i - 1);
                    if(j == length - 1)
                        i = j - 1;
                    else
                        i = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
                if(i == length - 1)
                    res+= s.charAt(i - 1);
        }
    System.out.println(res);    
    }
}
```

---

MIPS attempt:

```
.data
    string1: .asciiz "String? "
    input: .space 256
    newLine: .asciiz "\n"
    result: .space 256

.text

main:

        li $v0, 4    # print string1
        la $a0, string1
        syscall

        li $v0, 8        # read input
        la $a0, input
        li $a1, 255
        syscall

        li $t0, 0     #loop counter (length)
        lb $t2, newLine

   loop:
        lb $t1, ($a0) # load the content of the address stored in $a0 
        beq $t1, $t2, continue
        addi $t0, $t0, 1 # increment the loop counter
        addi $a0, $a0, 1 # go to next byte      
        j loop


   continue:   
        addi $t1, $zero, 0
        addi $a0, $zero, 0 
        bne $t0, 1, else0 # if length != 1, jump to else0

        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, input
        syscall 

   else0:
        li $t1, 1            #i = 1
        addi $t6, $t0, -1    # length - 1
        addi $t7, $t1, -2    # i - 2
        addi $t9, $t1, -1    # i - 1
     for_loop:
        bge $t1, $t0 print

     for_loop2:
        move $t3, $t1        # j = i
        addi $t8, $t3, -1    #j - 1
        bge $t3, $t0 increment_i

        add $a0, $zero, $t9    # s.charAt(i - 1)
        lb $s1, ($a0)
        addi $s0, $zero, 0

        add $s0, $zero, $t3    # s.charAt(j)
        lb $s2, ($a0)
        addi $s0, $zero, 0

        beq $s1, $s2, else1    # if s.charAt(i - 1) == s.charAt(j), jump to else1
        bne $t1, $t6, else2    # if i != length - 1

        add $s0, $zero, $t7    # s.charAt(i - 2)
        lb  $s3, ($a0)
        addi $a0, $zero, 0

        beq $t0, 2, continue2       # if length == 2 
        beq $s1, $s3, else3         #if s.charAt(i - 1) == s.charAt(i - 2), jump to else3

 continue2:       
        sb $s1, result($s4)  # res += s.charAt(i - 1)
        addi $s4, $s4, 1        
        sb $s2, result($s4)  #  res += s.charAt(j)
        addi $s4, $s4, 1
        j print

   else3:
        sb $s2, result($s4)  # res += s.charAt(j)
        addi $s4, $s4, 1
        j print

   else2:
        sb $s1, result($s4)  # res = s.charAt(i - 1)
        addi $s4, $s4, 1    
        bne $t3, $t6, else4
        move $t1, $t8
        addi $t1, $t1, 1
        j for_loop
   else4:
        move $t1, $t3
        addi $t1, $t1, 1
        j for_loop

   else1:
        bne $t1, $t6, increment_j
        sb $s1, result($s4)  # res = s.charAt(i - 1)
        addi $s4, $s4, 1 
        j print 
      increment_j:
          addi $t3, $t3, 1
          j for_loop2
      increment_i:
          addi $t1, $t1, 1
          j for_loop

   print:
        move $t4, $s4
        addi $s4, $zero, 0
      loop2:
        beq $s4, $t4, exit
        li $v0, 11
        la  $a0, result($s4)
        syscall
        addi $s4, $s4, 1
        j loop2   


exit:
        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Comment: What happens when you single step through it?

Comment: it stops at line 18, after reading input

Comment: What's on line 18?

Comment: It's the syscall for reading input. The strange thing is that when in Mars I single step throught it it stops at line 18, when I run entirely the program, it stops at line 54, where there's a runtime exception (address out of range)  on `lb $s1, ($a0)`

Comment: @Erik Eidt sorry, it stops at syscall because it's asking me for input

Comment: @ErikEidt I managed to solve it, now I'm going to post the correct version, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve the problems, I post the correct version so maybe someone could find it useful in the future.

```
.data
    string1: .asciiz "String? "
    input: .space 256
    newLine: .asciiz "\n"
    result: .space 256

.text

main:

        li $v0, 4    # print string1
        la $a0, string1
        syscall

        li $v0, 8        # read input
        la $a0, input
        li $a1, 255
        syscall

        li $t0, 0     #loop counter (length)
        lb $t2, newLine

   loop:
        lb $t1, ($a0) # load the content of the address stored in $a0 
        beq $t1, $t2, continue
        addi $t0, $t0, 1 # increment the loop counter
        addi $a0, $a0, 1 # go to next byte      
        j loop


   continue:   
        addi $t1, $zero, 0
        addi $a0, $zero, 0 
        bne $t0, 1, else0 # if length != 1, jump to else0

        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, input
        syscall 

   else0:
        li $t1, 1            #i = 1
        addi $t6, $t0, -1    # length - 1
     for_loop:
        bge $t1, $t0 print
        addi $t7, $t1, -2    # i - 2
        addi $t9, $t1, -1    # i - 1
        move $t3, $t1        # j = i
     for_loop2:
        addi $t8, $t3, -1    #j - 1
        bge $t3, $t0 increment_i

        add $a0, $zero, $t9    # s.charAt(i - 1)
        lb $s1, input($a0)
        addi $a0, $zero, 0

        add $a0, $zero, $t3    # s.charAt(j)
        lb $s2, input($a0)
        addi $a0, $zero, 0

        beq $s1, $s2, else1    # if s.charAt(i - 1) == s.charAt(j), jump to else1
        bne $t1, $t6, else2    # if i != length - 1, jump to else2

        add $a0, $zero, $t7    # s.charAt(i - 2)
        lb  $s3, input($a0)
        addi $a0, $zero, 0

        beq $t0, 2, continue2       # if length == 2 
        beq $s1, $s3, else3         #if s.charAt(i - 1) == s.charAt(i - 2), jump to else3

 continue2:       
        sb $s1, result($s4)  # res += s.charAt(i - 1)
        addi $s4, $s4, 1        
        sb $s2, result($s4)  #  res += s.charAt(j)
        addi $s4, $s4, 1
        j print

   else3:
        sb $s2, result($s4)  # res += s.charAt(j)
        addi $s4, $s4, 1
        j print

   else2:
        sb $s1, result($s4)  # res = s.charAt(i - 1)
        addi $s4, $s4, 1    
        bne $t3, $t6, else4 # if j != length - 1 
        move $t1, $t8       # i = j - 1
        addi $t1, $t1, 1
        j for_loop
   else4:
        move $t1, $t3
        addi $t1, $t1, 1
        j for_loop

   else1:
        bne $t1, $t6, increment_j   # if i != length - 1
        sb $s1, result($s4)  # res = s.charAt(i - 1)
        addi $s4, $s4, 1 
        j print 
      increment_j:
          addi $t3, $t3, 1
          j for_loop2
      increment_i:
          addi $t1, $t1, 1
          j for_loop

   print:
       li $v0, 4
       la $a0, result
       syscall


exit:
        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Comment: You should at least say what the problems were that you fixed.  Although probably most of the future value (if any) is the working code-dump, not the debugging of whatever was wrong with your original.  But still, code-dump answers with no text explanation are generally not good on Stack Overflow.  This implementation looks a lot larger than necessary; it should be possible to just keep an input and output pointer and scan input forwards, storing and incrementing output when you come to a character that doesn't match the last one you saw.  (Use a register to hold that, not a reload)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, your algorithm and implementation is *massively* overcomplicated.

All you need are a register to remember what input character you saw last, and input/output pointers (also in registers).  The inner loop finds the next new character, the outer loop stores it and increments the output pointer.

I haven't figured out why your implementation is such a huge mess (this is not a code-review), but I was curious how simple it was possible to make this.  Here's what I came up with:

```
.data
    input:  .asciiz "abbcddeffga\n"
    result: .ascii "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"    # poison to detect failure to store a \0
            .space 256

.text
_start:
        la      $t0, result     
        la      $t1, input    # read stdin if you want

        li      $t2, -1       # previous char: c = -1  (not equal to any possible unsigned byte value)
.outer:                         # do {
.uniq:                             # do {
        lbu     $t4, ($t1)            # c = *in++
        addiu   $t1, $t1, 1
        beq     $t4, $t2, .uniq    # }while(c == prev) find next new character

        move    $t2, $t4           # prev = c
        sb      $t4, ($t0)
        addiu   $t0, $t0, 1        # *out++ = c
        bnez    $t4, .outer     # }while(c != 0)  // note that 0 terminator is stored first

        la      $a0, result
        li      $v0, 4
        syscall                 # print_string(result)
exit:
        li    $v0, 10
        syscall
```

I tested this in MARS and it works for this input string.  It also works correctly for the empty string, handling that corner case without reading the input past that byte, and storing the terminating `0` to the output.  (Initializing $t2 = `prev` with `-1` makes this work: `lbu` can never produce a `-1` so we're guaranteed no false-positive `prev` matches on the first iteration.)

The terminating `0` will always be a new unique character so we don't need to special-case it, just let the regular loop store it.

I simplified even more by using a hard-coded input string.  The code to prompt for and read a string input is unrelated to the actual algorithm.  Adding that back in would be orthogonal to the `uniq(result, input)` functionality.

Also, [MARS has a print_string system call](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html) so I used that instead of looping manually over print_character.  The output string is 0-terminated so we can safely use that syscall.